# My wife and I VS My wife and myself

Tags: grammar, personal-pronouns

I've learned how to use "My wife and I" in a sentence. There are a lot of interesting materials on the internet:

https://www.grammarbank.com/my-friend-and-me.html
http://www.english-for-students.com/My-Friend.html
Etc.

But today I accidentally came across this video

https://twitter.com/business/status/1125412934354636800

and Prince Harry says: "Megan and myself had a baby boy"

When should we use "myself" instead of "I" and "me"?

For a non-native speaker it is a bit confusing.